# CakePdf on a php5.6 server

Tags: cakephp

The site is on a php5.6 server - shared hosting so installation is done manually using github and php-download.com.

We've chosen to use mpdf and I can create test files by calling it directly.

Our cake site is v3.x.

I've added the pdf extension to routes.php
I've added this to bootstrap.php

```
Plugin::load('CakePdf',['bootstrap' => true]);

Configure::write('CakePdf', [
    'engine' => 'CakePdf.MpdfEngine',
    'margin' => [
        'bottom' => 15,
        'left' => 50,
        'right' => 30,
        'top' => 45
    ],
    'orientation' => 'portrait',
    'download' => true
]);
```

In my "forms" controller I have 2 functions - they both throw errors on the homepage.

```
//before the class
use CakePdf\Pdf\CakePdf;

//in the class
    function test(){
        $this->viewBuilder()->setClassName('CakePdf.Pdf');
        $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout('default');
        
        $this->viewBuilder()->options([
            'pdfConfig' => [
                'engine' => 'CakePdf.MpdfEngine',
                'download' => true,
                'title' => 'My Form',
                'filename' => 'Form1.pdf'
            ]
        ]);       
    }
    
    function test1(){
        
        $pdf_path = WWW_ROOT . 'tmp/tests/'.date('Y-m-d') . DS . 'test1.pdf';
        
        //$CakePdf = new CakePdf();
        $CakePdf = new \CakePdf\Pdf\CakePdf\CakePdf();
        debug($CakePdf);
        exit;
    $CakePdf->template('test', 'pdf/default');
    $pdf = $CakePdf->output();
    $pdf = $CakePdf->write($pdf_path);
    }
```

My error log for /forms/test1 is probably the most useful - in particular the bit where there's the extra 'CakePdf' in the first line

```
2020-10-12 16:30:12 Error: [Cake\Error\FatalErrorException] Class 'CakePdf\Pdf\CakePdf\CakePdf' not found in /var/www/www.mysite.com/public_html/src/Controller/FormsController.php on line 343
Request URL: /forms/test1.pdf
Stack Trace:
#0 /var/www/www.mysite.com/public_html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/BaseErrorHandler.php(105): Cake\Error\BaseErrorHandler->handleFatalError(1, 'Class 'CakePdf\\...', '/var/www/www.my...', 343)
#1 [internal function]: Cake\Error\BaseErrorHandler->Cake\Error\{closure}()
#2 {main}
```

Comment: Well, that is to be expected, is it not? Your code is explicitly asking for `\CakePdf\Pdf\CakePdf\CakePdf`, while the actual fully qualified name is `CakePdf\Pdf\CakePdf`.

Comment: You'd think, but take it out and I get the same error.

Comment: That might very well be the case (from looking at the code the message would most likely be a little different), but I wouldn't know, as the question shows the case with the wrong FQN, which is expected to fail in exactly that way. I would suggest to post the code how it's supposed to be, alongside the related error message.